# GNU Octave reports: unknown or ambiguous terminal type on OS X

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am trying to plot with Octave and GNUPlot on OS X 10.10.5. I have Octave and GNUPlot installed via homebrew but when I try to plot I get the following error

```
gnuplot> set terminal aqua enhanced title "Figure 1" size 560 420  font "*,6.66667" dashlength 1
                  ^
line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution was to install aquaterm e.g.

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/aquaterm
```

and then do

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-aquaterm
```